# npm update throws node-sass error

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

sometime ago I used node-sass in one of my projects. Now when I write `npm update`or `npm install` in any project (which doesn't use node-sass at all) I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! node-sass@3.3.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.3.2 postinstall script 'node scripts/build.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
```

I tried so far:

- npm rebuild
- npm rebuild node-sass
- npm uninstall -g node-sass
- npm install -g npde-sass@2 (somewhere I read that v2 doesn't have the problem)

my node version is v5.1.0

I don't need node-sass at all, but somehow it throws an error, which I can't explain at all. Has anyone an idea on how to get rid of this?

Comment: What OS are you running this on ? Have you seen https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md ?

Comment: i have mac os x, and yes I've read the troubleshooting, I also read all of the github issues they have on this topic.
what I don't understand is how my project - not related to node-sass at all - can fail when typing `npm install/update` just because of node-sass

Comment: There must be some dependency, I have run into similar problems in the past and sometimes had to compile from source. Have you tried SUDO (i.e running the Install as Root) ?

Comment: at first I had it installed with sudo, then I reinstalled it without sudo (which seems to be the way to go in node >= 4.0, but no effect. Everything works fine with node 0.10, but the newer versions cause this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using harp in 0.18 which seems to have a bug. 0.20.1 fixed this issue for me